# Is it possible to create google sheet template programmatically?

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is it possible to create google sheet template programmatically? If yes how to do it? I know I am suppose to check API documentation but I am not a technical person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is supported as of now.

I searched in [Introduction to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) docs for a guide on how to do operations with Sheets API but have not found an explicit guide on how to do this.

You can also check Spreadsheet using [Google App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) but there is no mention as well.

Comment: I want to create a template not sheet.

Comment: You can always send them a [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Sheets).